# Instrument Variable Approach for a system of 6 endogenous variables

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

I am working on an econometric model that features 6 endogenous variables and several exogenous variables. The data is in panel form, that is, we are observing 130 countries over 17 years. Our endogenous variables are things like democracy and income per capita. The issue arises in trying to identify reverse causality. FInding 6 different instruments, especially for variables like income per capita, seems like an impossible task. Is there any way to establish casuality/deal with the endogeneity issues? If not, are there any classical instruments for income per capita?

Edit:

The variables are as follows:

Endogenous:
Statehood: a measure of state fragility
EIU: The Economist's measure of democracy
Corruption
Income per capita
Average years of education
GINI: A measure on inequality

Exogenous:
Location
Geographical features (landlocked, access to resources, etc)
colonial history
demographic make up

Comment: 6...good luck. (Might help people give answers if you say what the dependent variable is.) Econ SE might be another place to try.

Comment: Can you draw a causal diagram?

Comment: Michael, I've given more info on the dependant variables. Adrian, in essence, all 6 of the endogenous effect one another, while each of the exogenous affect each of the endogenous. I'm unaware of what a causal diagram is, my apologies. Cursory googling shows it would likely be the 6 endogenous with arrows effecting one another, with the exogenous effecting each endogenous and not one another.